# QT How to apply Style Sheet to columns

Tags: qt, styles, qtreewidget

I am creating a Qt GUI app and i can not apply color or style sheet to the columns tab in QTreeWidget (the white color in the picture below)

[image]

anyone can help to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved using this code:

```
ui->treeWidget->header()->setStyleSheet("QHeaderView::section {\
                                            color: black;\
                                            padding: 2px;\
                                            height: 40px;\
                                            border: 0px solid #567dbc;\
                                            border-left:0px;\
                                            border-right:0px;\
                                            background: #D7D7D7;\
                                        }");
```